# Keras tf backend predict speed slow for batch size of 1

Tags: python, performance, keras

I am combining a Monte-Carlo Tree Search with a convolutional neural network as the rollout policy. I've identified the Keras model.predict function as being very slow. After experimentation, I found that surprisingly model parameter size and prediction sample size don't affect the speed significantly. For reference:

- 0.00135549 s for 3 samples with batch_size = 3
- 0.00303991 s for 3 samples with batch_size = 1
- 0.00115528 s for 1 sample with batch_size = 1
- 0.00136132 s for 10 samples with batch_size = 10

as you can see I can predict 10 samples at about the same speed as 1 sample. The change is also very minimal though noticeable if I decrease parameter size by 100X but I'd rather not change parameter size by that much anyway. In addition, the predict function is very slow the first time run through (~0.2s) though I don't think that's the problem here since the same model is predicting multiple times.

I wonder if there is some workaround because clearly the 10 samples can be evaluated very quickly, all I want to be able to do is predict the samples at different times and not all at once since I need to update the Tree Search before making a new prediction. Perhaps should I work with tensorflow instead?

Answer (score 2):

The batch size controls parallelism when predicting, so it is expected that increasing the batch size will have better performance, as you can use more cores and use GPU more efficiently.

You cannot really workaround, there is nothing really to work around, using a batch size of one is the worst case for performance. Maybe you should look into a smaller network that is faster to predict, or predict on the CPU if your experiments are done in a GPU, to minimize overhead due to transfer.

Don't forget that `model.predict` does a full forward pass of the network, so its speed completely depends on the network architecture.

Comment: If I call predict multiple times, does keras reload the gpu with all the weights on every call or does it keep the weights in the gpu between calls? My model has a million parameters, but the input and output vectors are only a few bytes, and it's slow slow.

Comment: @grabbag That sounds like you should ask your own question.

Answer (score 2):

One way that gave me a speed up was switching from `model.predict(x)` to,

```
model.predict_on_batch(x)
```

making sure your x shape has 1 as the first dimension.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think working with pure Tensorflow would change the performance much. Keras is a high-level API for low-level Tensorflow primitives. You could use a smaller model instead, like MobileNetV3 or EfficientNet, but this would require retraining.

If you need to remain with the existing model, you could try [OpenVINO](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/openvino_docs_install_guides_overview.html). OpenVINO is optimized for Intel hardware, but it should work with any CPU. It optimizes your model by converting to Intermediate Representation (IR), performing graph pruning and fusing some operations into others while preserving accuracy. Then it uses vectorization in runtime.

It's rather straightforward to convert the Keras model to OpenVINO. The full tutorial on how to do it can be found [here](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/openvino_notebooks/tree/main/notebooks/101-tensorflow-to-openvino). Some snippets are below.

**Install OpenVINO**

The easiest way to do it is using PIP. Alternatively, you can use [this tool](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/openvino-toolkit/download.html) to find the best way in your case.

```
pip install openvino-dev[tensorflow2]
```

**Save your model as SavedModel**

OpenVINO is not able to convert the HDF5 model, so you have to save it as SavedModel first.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from custom_layer import CustomLayer
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model.h5', custom_objects={'CustomLayer': CustomLayer})
tf.saved_model.save(model, 'model')
```

**Use Model Optimizer to convert SavedModel model**

The Model Optimizer is a command-line tool that comes from OpenVINO Development Package. It converts the Tensorflow model to IR, a default format for OpenVINO. You can also try the precision of FP16, which should give you better performance without a significant accuracy drop (change data_type). Run in the command line:

```
mo --saved_model_dir "model" --data_type FP32 --output_dir "model_ir"
```

**Run the inference**

The converted model can be loaded by the runtime and compiled for a specific device, e.g., CPU or GPU (integrated into your CPU like Intel HD Graphics). If you don't know what the best choice for you is, use AUTO. You care about latency, so I suggest adding a performance hint (as shown below) to use the device that fulfills your requirement.

```
# Load the network
ie = Core()
model_ir = ie.read_model(model="model_ir/model.xml")
compiled_model_ir = ie.compile_model(model=model_ir, device_name="AUTO", config={"PERFORMANCE_HINT":"LATENCY"})

# Get output layer
output_layer_ir = compiled_model_ir.output(0)

# Run inference on the input image
result = compiled_model_ir([input_image])[output_layer_ir]
```

Disclaimer: I work on OpenVINO.